# Is there any way to restrict number of users accesing the file

Tags: c++, file, c++11, asynchronous

I am coding in a huge dependant environment, where multiple processes are running. In this ecosystem, there in one file which needs to modified by almost all processes running.

Here every process is having a different file descriptor for the same file path.

Is there any way I can restrict the file opening such that only one instance of that file, can be opened, and all other instances be queued ?

I have tried mutex and flock, but they don't really serve the purpose.

Please tell me any way that you feel might help !

Comment: The answer - if there is one - will depend upon the operating system. Can you tag the correct one?

Comment: What's wrong with `flock`?

Comment: flock was slowing down my system quite a bit.

Comment: @TanveerBadar linux os

Answer (score 2):

1.If all the process are on the same server, you can try os api, ex:

linux:
https://gavv.github.io/articles/file-locks/

windows:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/fileapi/nf-fileapi-lockfileex

2.If all the process are not on the same server, you need other ways to do this, ex:

zookeeper, redis or a temp lock file.

3.If you can change the arch of your ecosystem, you'd better redesign it.

One 'file service' to access all the files, while other services just invoke the 'file service'.

Comment: Thanks, but i am not the architect. But more importantly that is the requirement that it must a single file. And yes it's on a single server